# Unable to fetch data from controller in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty much new to AngularJS. In fact, this is my first day. What I'm trying to do here is to fetch data from a controller I made and show it in the view. But I don't know why, it's not simply working.

My data is a list of students. All I'm trying to do is to show the list of students in a list order and filter the list according to the name entered in a textbox.

My code is pretty simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

      Student Name:
     <br />
      <input type="text" ng-model="sname" /> {{ sname }} 
    <div id="mvvm_communication" class="container" data-ng-controller="simpleController">

      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="stud in students | filter:sname  | orderBy:'firstname'" >{{stud.firstname | lowercase }}, {{stud.lastname| uppercase }}</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <script>
      function simpleController($scope)
      {
        $scope.students=[
               {firstname:'Jordan',lastname:'Rains'},
               {firstname:'Michael',lastname:'Jordan'},
               {firstname:'John',lastname:'Doe'},
               {firstname:'John',lastname:'Smith'},
               {firstname:'Simcha',lastname:'Michelle'},
               {firstname:'Sydney',lastname:'Rivers'},
               {firstname:'Summer',lastname:'Rose'},
               {firstname:'Georgia',lastname:'Schubert'},
               {firstname:'Rosalie',lastname:'Fayadh'}
              ];

      }      
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/ktbpn58o/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your controller!

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('simpleController', ['$scope', simpleController]);
```

And then you also need to put a name into `ng-app`.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew about this

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/ktbpn58o/1/):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="simpleController">
    <h1>Hello Student!</h1>   Student Name:<br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="sname" /> {{ sname }} 
    <div id="mvvm_communication" class="container">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="stud in students | filter:sname  | orderBy:'firstname'" >{{stud.firstname | lowercase }}, {{stud.lastname| uppercase }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('simpleController', function($scope) {

        $scope.students=[
               {firstname:'Jordan',lastname:'Rains'},
               {firstname:'Michael',lastname:'Jordan'},
               {firstname:'John',lastname:'Doe'},
               {firstname:'John',lastname:'Smith'},
               {firstname:'Simcha',lastname:'Michelle'},
               {firstname:'Sydney',lastname:'Rivers'},
               {firstname:'Summer',lastname:'Rose'},
               {firstname:'Georgia',lastname:'Schubert'},
               {firstname:'Rosalie',lastname:'Fayadh'}
              ]; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define an angular module:

```
      angular.module('app', []).controller('simpleController', simpleController);
```

see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/umfx4y4c/)